# "onlinemeeting cannot be null" error when creating new meeting with beta API

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to create a new meeting as per [the documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/application_post_onlinemeetings):

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/app/onlineMeetings
```

(bearer token included - works fine with other operations)

```
{
  "meetingType": "meetNow",
  "participants": {
    "organizer": {
      "identity": {
        "user": {
          "id": "54f84a95-91c1-49f1-8d81-4632342e2c1e"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "startTime": "2018-10-10T14:46:02Z",
  "subject": "my meeting"
}
```

I get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "{\"message\":\"onlinemeeting cannot be null.\"}",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "da54bfec-c987-4e02-b4b6-1844801d5f00",
      "date": "2018-10-18T09:52:25"
    }
  }
}
```

any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is the content-type that you're posting?

Comment: application/json. Testing with postman.

Comment: Can you please try "MeetNow" instead of "meetNow" and let us know is it working without any error?

Comment: @Arun-MSFT This didn't solve it unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

A little late, but for other googlelers,

there is an error it is not startTime, but StartDateTime and the EndDateTime is missing.

your json should look like

```
{
  "startDateTime":"2019-09-09T14:33:30.8546353z",
  "endDateTime":"2019-09-09T15:03:30.8566356z",
  "subject":"Subject of schedule",
  "participants": {
    "organizer": {
      "identity": {
        "user": {
          "id": "my oid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```