# MS Graph create onlineMeeting: "onlinemeeting cannot be null."

Tags: javascript, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm currently trying to create online meetings using the Graph Explorer and facing a similiar problem like in this question: [onlinemeeting-cannot-be-null-error-when-creating-new-meeting-with-beta-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52871568/onlinemeeting-cannot-be-null-error-when-creating-new-meeting-with-beta-api).

Whenever I'm sending a Post request to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings the answer is a **400 Bad Request** error with message: **onlinemeeting cannot be null**. The body looks like the example from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

```
{
  startDateTime:"2020-09-09T14:33:30.8546353-07:00",
  endDateTime:"2020-009-09T15:03:30.8566356-07:00",
  subject:"test"
}
```

No matter what, I can't get this to work. Other endpoints work well and the API permissions fit the requirements. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Could you please try this request body and see if this helps:
{
  "startDateTime":"2020-03-04T16:00:30.8546353-07:00",
  "endDateTime":"2020-03-04T16:30:30.8566356-07:00",
  "subject":"Application Token Meeting",
  "participants": {
    "organizer": {
      "identity": {
        "user": {
          "id": "ID of the user"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: Thanks! Adding the organizer worked as pointed out in the answer.

Comment: i faced the same problem, but adding the organizer didn't fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `participants` should be provided in the `onlineMeeting` resource, `participants` is one of properties in [onlineMeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/graph/api/resources/onlinemeeting?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) object, you can also add other properties of `onlineMeeting`.

So you need to add it to your request body, [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/api/application-post-onlinemeetings.md) is a sample for your reference:

```
{
  "startDateTime":"2019-09-09T14:33:30.8546353-07:00",
  "endDateTime":"2019-09-09T15:03:30.8566356-07:00",
  "subject":"Application Token Meeting",
  "participants": {
    "organizer": {
      "identity": {
        "user": {
          "id": "550fae72-d251-43ec-868c-373732c2704f"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Now it works. I just dont get it, as I'm sure I tried adding the organizer before, but maybe I used the wrong format.

Thank you so much!