# Microsoft Graph API Create OnlineMeetings Error - Expected not null\r\nParameter name: meeting

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

My issue looks very similar to:

[Microsoft Graph API OnlineMeetings Error - Expected not null\r\nParameter name: meeting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65420779/microsoft-graph-api-onlinemeetings-error-expected-not-null-r-nparameter-name)

However the posted solution is not working for me. Presently I'm using postman and posting to:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/MyAzureUserObjectID/onlineMeetings

Currently this is my body:

```
{
  "startDateTime":"2021-07-12T14:30:34.2444915-07:00",
  "endDateTime":"2021-07-12T15:00:34.2464912-07:00",
  "subject":"Application Token Meeting 2",
  "participants": {
    "organizer": {
      "identity": {
        "user": {
          "id": "MyAzureUserObjectIDHere"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried a few variations of participants and fields but always get:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidArgument",
        "message": "Expected not null\r\nParameter name: meeting",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "3ea5c99c-a346-4c3a-8f38-dcdc9fb4d864",
            "date": "2021-03-23T19:59:28",
            "client-request-id": "3ea5c99c-a346-4c3a-8f38-dcdc9fb4d864"
        }
    }
}
```

returned. Has anyone had a similar issue/have any idea what I might do get this to work?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using App Context flow and getting the App token?

Comment: Yes, I've been able to retrieve a token using the app context flow without issue (before I correctly sorted out the token I'd get an invalid token error)

Comment: Check if the same user is present in your AAD tenant ot not

Comment: I'm using my user which I looked up in my AAD tenant for both the url object id and the participant organizer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem which also wasn't resolved by simply adding the participant.

The thing that fixed it for me was using the correct content type in the header. As I had started with the starter project from Microsoft Teams, I had copied and pasted some of their example code for the meeting request. You need to use 'Content-type': 'application/json'.

Also for the body, I had to use JSON.stringify around it to get it to function correctly.